# Новый репозиторий на основе собственного существующего - как правильно сделать?

Tags: git, android-studio, android, github

**Дано:**

Проект-шаблон (андроид приложение, Android Studio), на основе коего желаю создать другие проекты и вести их в отдельных репозиториях.

**Возможные решения:**

1. Создать новый проект в AS, скопировать туда файлы, расшарить его на гитхаб.
2. Клонировать проект и потом запушить его в другой репозиторий.
3. Создать новую ветку (branch) в проекте и не плодить новых репозиториев.

**Вопрос:**

Таки как лучше всего поступить в данном случае?

*P.S.* *Понятия и термины могут быть попутаны, с **git** знаком крайне поверхностно.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

категории хуже/лучше применимы только в контексте стоящих перед вами задач.

подозреваю, что задачи эти вряд ли сформулированы, а потому имеет смысл не пользоваться «радикальным» первым вариантом (копирование файлов), полностью разрывающим связь между репозиторием с шаблоном и репозиториями с проектами.

с технической точки зрения второй и третий варианты практически не отличаются: всё равно для каждого проекта вам потребуется отдельный каталог с рабочей копией файлов, а, соответственно, и отдельный репозиторий (содержимое каталога `.git`), а уж будут ли все эти репозитории синхронизироваться с одним репозиторием, двумя или с сотней (или вообще ни с одним) — с технической точки зрения несущественно.

Comment: Шаблон - это внешний вид, на коий  буду прикручивать логику (например, вывод инфы с разных сайтов, по приложению на сайт). Вопрос в том, что меня смущает выделять ветки для каждого нового сайта вместо создания нового репозитория с копией кода шаблона. Но может быть так и надо (читай - так негласно принято в подобных случаях)? Просто я попытался в `GitHub`-е форкнуть свой репозиторий и... Ничего не произошло. Совсем. Вот я и в недоумении...

Comment: выполняя `git clone ...` вы **уже** делаете «форк», т.е. полноценную копию репозитория, **ничем** не уступающую «оригиналу». эту копию вы затем можете ещё много раз «форкнуть» в, например, вновь созданные пустые репозитории на *github*-е (или где-либо ещё) с помощью команды `git push ...`.

Comment: *я попытался в GitHub-е форкнуть свой репозиторий и... Ничего не произошло* — к *git*-у это отношения не имеет. все эти «форки», «пулл-реквесты» и тому подобные гитхабовские «плюшки» — это чисто организационные вещи. для организации совместной работы. организовывать же совместную работу с самим собой как-то не очень логично, потому вам и не дали этого сделать.

Comment: Т.е. я могу в AS клонировать свой репозиторий с `GitHub`, что-то с ним сделать, запушить его в другой репозиторий на `GitHub` (т.е. п.2) и это будет нормально практика?

Comment: да хоть в тысячу репозиториев: локальных, удалённых (на своих серверах или в публично доступных типа *github*-а). главное, потом не запутаться — для чего каждый из них нужен.

Comment: ОК, понял, спасибо)